# How can I condense a bunch of if/else statements

Tags: if-statement

So I have a big lump of code that is taking up a large area of space + I have many of these.
What would be the best way to condense something like what I have attached to this post?

```
if(number == 1) {
    System.out.println("1");
}
else if(number == 2) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
else if(number == 3) {
    System.out.println("3");
}
else if(number == 4) {
    System.out.println("4");
}
else if(number == 5) {
    System.out.println("5");
}
else if(number == 6) {
    System.out.println("6");
}
else if(number == 7) {
    System.out.println("7");
}
else if(number == 8) {
    System.out.println("8");
}
```

I'm just getting into to programming, so this would probably be a good learning experience, to understand how it works too! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.out.println(number)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// switch statement in Java 
switch(number) {
   case 1:
      System.out.println("1");
      break;
   
   case 2:
      System.out.println("2");
      break;
   
   // We can have any number of case statements
   // below is default statement, used when none of the cases is true. 
   // No break is needed in the default case.
   default: 
      // Default statements
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just what I needed!
Also thanks to the guy who suggested to just print the number, It was just an example I posted, should have made that clear, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

As of JDK 14, you can also use the new *switch expressions* syntax. See this example:

```java
public static void print(int number) {
    String s = switch(number) {
        case 1 -> "1";
        case 2 -> "2";
        case 3, 4, 5  -> "3, 4 or 5";
        default -> Integer.toString(number);
    };
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

For further information, see [JEP 361](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361).